# Event handler for iframe loaded not firing

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe in my HTML, and I want to be notified when it's fully loaded. I have this testcase:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addListener(el, type, func, capture) {
    if (el.addEventListener){
        el.addEventListener(type, func, capture); 
    } else if (el.attachEvent){
        el.attachEvent('on'+type, func);
    }
}
function addhandlers(frame) {
    addListener(frame, "load", function(e) { onDomLoaded(e); }, true);
}
function onDomLoaded(e) {
    alert("loaded");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<input type="button" value="Add handlers" onclick="addhandlers(window.frames[0]);" />
</form>

<iframe id="frm" height="300" src="test.htm" width="700"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The test.htm file is just a standard html file with a few regular  links to places.

First I click the Add Handlers button to add the listeners, then I click any link in test.htm inside the iframe. My expectation is that I get an alert, but nothing happens. Why, and how do I solve it? I'm currently looking for a solution that works in firefox and IE (but nothing happens in either browser).

Comment: **You cannot access an IFrame not in your domain, period**. It's a security hole in the size of Texas. Most, if not all modern browsers prevent it internally. I suggest you read about XSS (cross site scripting) to understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to include javascript within test.htm

test.htm:

```
function addListener(el, type, func, capture) {
    if (el.addEventListener){
            el.addEventListener(type, func, capture); 
    } else if (el.attachEvent){
            el.attachEvent('on'+type, func);
    }
}
function addhandlers(frame) {
        addListener(frame, "load", function(e) { onDomLoaded(e); }, true);
}

function onDomLoaded(e) {  
   window.parent.iframeLoaded()
}
```

parentpage.htm:

```
function iframeLoaded() {
    alert('loaded');
}
```

Note that this only works if both files are on the same domain

Comment: unfortunately I cannot change the test.htm page in the real setting, as it may be on another domain.